# The use of where in Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
var a = from sc in context.SchoolClass
                    join bc in context.BookClass
                    on sc.ClassID equals bc.ClassID  into temp
                    from tt in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where  bc.ClassID == null && sc.SchoolYear == "2015" 
                    select sc.ClassID;
```

Question: In the above code, " bc.ClassID == null " bc tip does not exist!
I know "bc.ClassID == null" is wrong, but I don't know how to make this right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing a `left join` here, you won't be able to access the properties of `bc`, you can access the properties via `tt` and it may contain null for non matching rows. Try this:-

```
var a = from sc in context.SchoolClass
        join bc in context.BookClass
        on sc.ClassID equals bc.ClassID  into temp
        from tt in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where  tt.ClassID == null && sc.SchoolYear == "2015" 
        select sc.ClassID;
```

Comment: @SillyMe - You're Welcome:) Please check - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work  and do accept the answer if that helped you.

Comment: “ into temp  ” Is this temporary table?

Comment: @SillyMe - Yeah you can think of it. It's group join, check this- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx